# a list of YAML timezone?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I am using YAML to set cron jobs for my Google Apple Engine python project.

```
schedule: every monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday 03:30
timezone: America/New_York
```

I am wondering if anyone has a list of all acceptable timezone format?

I copied it from an example and "America/New_York" works for me now. It would be nice to have a list to check all the timezones over the world, a map would be even better representation.

I don't seem to find any information on that, can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=ja#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format)

The timezone should be the name of a standard [zoneinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zoneinfo_time_zones) time zone name. If you don't specify a timezone, the schedule will be in UTC (also known as GMT).

You will find the list in zoneinfo link.